# My app cant run on android 6 but can run if run on android 9-11

Tags: java, android, fragment, layout-inflater, forceclose

when i run my app on android 9, android 10, and android 11. my app runs fine without a hitch. when i run it on android 6, the app experiences force close on the way to the main fragment.

when i try to see error in logcat, shows error in mainFragment, in inflater. Why did it happen?

**Logcat**

```
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.hp.ali.ecomerceapp.fragments.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:47)
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.hp.ali.ecomerceapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.EcomerceApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".activities.TentangAplikasi"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.KebijakanPrivasi" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.VerifikasiPesanan" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.StatusPesanan" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SwipeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SwipeUkaki" />
        <activity android:name=".login.InputOTPActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.OTPAuthActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.EditAlamat" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.EditProfile" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.Other"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.CartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.CheckoutActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ProductDetail" />
        <activity android:name=".login.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".login.LogInActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.snapchat.kit.sdk.clientId"
            android:value="f4cad14a-c276-4d02-9d2e-683e038d044d" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.snapchat.kit.sdk.redirectUrl"
            android:value="ecomerceapp://snap-kit/oauth2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.snapchat.kit.sdk.scopes"
            android:resource="@array/snap_connect_scopes" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.snapchat.kit.sdk.SnapKitActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="snap-kit"
                    android:path="/oauth2"
                    android:scheme="ecomerceapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.snapchat.android" />
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

**Gradle**

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
        ndkVersion "21.3.6528147"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.hp.ali.ecomerceapp"
            minSdkVersion 20
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 18
            versionName "1.8"
            multiDexEnabled true
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                ndk{
                    debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
                }
            }
    
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }
    ext {
        snapKitSdkVersion = '1.4.0'
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    
        //For Google Log-in
        implementation 'com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.1.0'
    
        //Allert
        implementation 'com.github.TutorialsAndroid:KAlertDialog:v14.0.19'
    
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
        implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
        implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        implementation 'com.yarolegovich:sliding-root-nav:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.github.hajiyevelnur92:intentanimation:1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.mig35:carousellayoutmanager:+'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
        implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
        implementation([
                'com.snapchat.kit.sdk:creative:1.10.0',
                'com.snapchat.kit.sdk:core:1.10.0'
        ])
    
        //Country Code Picker
        implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.0'
        implementation "com.snapchat.kit.sdk:login:$snapKitSdkVersion"
        implementation "com.snapchat.kit.sdk:core:$snapKitSdkVersion"
        //Page Indicator View
        implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3'
    
        //carouselview
        compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    
    
    }
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AppCompatImageView` instead `ImageView`, and `app:srcCompat` instead `android:src` in the XML.

But, according to [AppCompatImageView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageView), it should be replaced automatically if you use `AppCompatActivity`:

> This will automatically be used when you use [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by [`appcompat`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat). You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

So, please make your activity inherits from `AppCompatActivity`.